# converting to codeigniter input post?

Tags: php, codeigniter

When creating my permissions I have to methods, permission/access and permission/modify.

But I am wanting to use codeigniter input post method but not sure on correct method for adding two parts like below.

How can I convert the `$this->request->post['permission']['access']` and `$this->request->post['permission']['modify']` to codeigniter way

```
if (isset($this->request->post['permission']['access'])) {
$data['access'] = $this->request->post['permission']['access'];
} elseif (isset($user_group_info['permission']['access'])) {
$data['access'] = $user_group_info['permission']['access'];
} else {
$data['access'] = array();
}

if (isset($this->request->post['permission']['modify'])) {
$data['modify'] = $this->request->post['permission']['modify'];
} elseif (isset($user_group_info['permission']['modify'])) {
$data['modify'] = $user_group_info['permission']['modify'];
} else {
$data['modify'] = array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is how your form is sending the post data, I mean in multi-dimensional array? And I usually use:

```
 $this->input->post('postedValue');
```

Post is a method, you should you small brackets `()`.

---

### Update

I don't know how you are posting data through submit form or through ajax, either way, check posted values. Let's suppose if data posted through Ajax is like this.

[image]

Then I use `$this->input->post('TabDesc');` and same goes for `TabName` and `TabDesc`.

Now in your case if data is posted as array as you showed,
try this:

`$this->input->post('['permission']['access']');`

but I am doubtful about this post, that's why I asked you to check if your form is really posting like the way you are trying to get as multi-dimensional.

But also see, if your form is posting like this:

[image]

then you can try like this:

`$textValue = $this->input->post('text['value']');`

Comment: I know about post value but unsure if where to add the second value access or modify. I do not understand the user guide on that way. My custom post library lets me use it but would prefer codeigniter post. The data gets serialized when posted.

Comment: @acoderslife
i don't know how is your form values posted. normally its simple ones when you post. See the name attribute of the form and try to get it with $this->input->post('input_name_here');
You can use `Firebug` to check values of posted data if you are using ajax post.
See the Update also Please.

Answer (score 0):

You can descrypted your input post before.
the type is accsess & modify.

maybe you can change your code like this

```
$postType = $this->input->post('permission);

$data['access'] = $postType['access'];
$data['modify] = $postType['modify'];
```

hope this helpful